# How to disable buttons in React Native with another button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm new to react-native and I'm trying to create an application where it requires me to enable or disable buttons based on the press of a button. I'm trying using UseState But I'm confused as to how I can use multiple useState. For Example

Initial State:

Button A - Enabled
Button B - Disabled
Button C - Disabled
Button D - Disabled

On Press Button A

Button A - Disabled
Button B - Enabled
Button C - Enabled
Button D - Enabled

On Press Button C

Button A - Disabled
Button B - Disabled
Button C - Disabled
Button D - Enabled and so on. Can anyone help me to how I can use Mulitple use state in React Native

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hold them in different states, like this:

```
const [buttonAEnabled, setButtonAEnabled] = useState(true);
const [buttonBEnabled, setButtonBEnabled] = useState(false);
const [buttonCEnabled, setButtonCEnabled] = useState(false);
const [buttonDEnabled, setButtonDEnabled] = useState(false);
```

This way, they are initialized like the way you wanted, button A is enabled and rest of the buttons are disabled.

I will assume that you will be using TouchableOpacity for the buttons, using disabled prop, you can bind the buttons with your state.

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  {/* Button A */}
  <TouchableOpacity
    disabled={!buttonAEnabled}
    onPress={handleButtonAPressed}
    style={styles.button}
  >
    <Text>Button A</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>

  {/* Button B */}
  <TouchableOpacity
    disabled={!buttonBEnabled}
    onPress={handleButtonBPressed}
    style={styles.button}
  >
    <Text>Button B</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>

  {/* Button C */}
  <TouchableOpacity
    disabled={!buttonCEnabled}
    onPress={handleButtonCPressed}
    style={styles.button}
  >
    <Text>Button C</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>

  {/* Button D */}
  <TouchableOpacity
    disabled={!buttonDEnabled}
    onPress={handleButtonDPressed}
    style={styles.button}
  >
    <Text>Button D</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

Lastly, you should handle button presses.

```
const handleButtonAPressed = () => {
  setButtonAEnabled(false);
  setButtonBEnabled(true);
  setButtonCEnabled(true);
  setButtonDEnabled(true);
};

const handleButtonBPressed = () => {
  // Whatever you want to do when button B is pressed
};

const handleButtonCPressed = () => {
  setButtonAEnabled(false);
  setButtonBEnabled(false);
  setButtonCEnabled(false);
  setButtonDEnabled(true);
};

const handleButtonDPressed = () => {
  // Whatever you want to do when button D is pressed
};
```

You can also hold the button states as a single object like below:

```
const [buttonsActivityStatus, setButtonsActivityStatus] = useState({
  buttonA: true,
  buttonB: false,
  buttonC: false,
  buttonD: false,
});
```

Then you would have to change the state in a different way. Something like this:

```
setButtonsActivityStatus({
  buttonA: false,
  buttonB: true,
  buttonC: true,
  buttonD: true,
});
```

With this single object way, you can also use destructuring to make changing state shorter if you don't want to change every single state. For example, the code below will only change the state of buttonB to true, and keep the rest of the buttons the same.

```
setButtonsActivityStatus((oldStatus) => ({
  ...oldStatus,
  buttonB: true,
}));
```

You can also check out [this demo](https://snack.expo.io/@mertcansegmen/lonely-ice-cream) of this whole thing.